# How to return the right {site_short_name} in a Channel Entries Tag when using MSM

Tags: multi-site-manager

I'm using MSM to manage a number of sites, but on one of them I need to list ALL news items across ALL sites (which is easy!) ... however I need to identify which site each item has come from by either site_id or site_short_name, etc.

So... I'm looking for:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" site="siteA|siteB|siteC"} 
{count}. {title} - {site_short_name}<br />
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

To result in:

```
1. My great title - siteB<br />
2. Another great title - siteA<br />
3. Yet another great title - siteC<br />
```

Unfortunately, the {site_short_name} is only coming back with the site_short_name of the site I am actually on.  For example if the above code is on Site A, it comes back with the results:

```
1. My great title - siteA<br />
2. Another great title - siteA<br />
3. Yet another great title - siteA<br />
```

Anyone able to help?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it would be better to create to global variables within the index.php files of each site. In the index.php of each site you can have the code like:

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array('site_1_short_name' => '[short name of site 1]',  'site_2_short_name' => '[short name of site 2]');
```

**Please note**: You need to put this global variables assignments array above the last line of code i.e above the line of code:

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter'.EXT;
```

within index.php

The global variables {site_1_short_name} and {site_2_short_name} can be used anywhere within the templates.

**Updated**:

I don't think above would work.

The small SQL can be used with Query module:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT exp_sites.site_name AS SiteShortName FROM exp_sites, exp_channel_titles
WHERE exp_sites.site_id=exp_channel_titles.site_id AND exp_channel_titles.entry_id='{entry_id}'"}

{SiteShortName}

{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Doesn't help, though, because he's pulling in stuff from multiple sites in the same channel:entries loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bhashkar ... but adrienne is right. I need to know which site the ENTRY is from. Once I'm on a site, I can get the site_short_name already.

Comment: Yes, I just realize that it wouldn't work. I think, if you can use sql with the query module it can output right output for site_short_name. I put this query in my answer.

Comment: Ah! Nice. That works perfectly.  There won't actually be so many items on each page that the extra few Query calls will make any difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use {entry_site_id}

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#entry-site-id

And this Query module:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT site_name FROM exp_sites WHERE site_id='{entry_site_id}'"}
    {site_name}
{/exp:query}
```

---

This add-on can help too: Blog Info

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/blog-info